# Does a frequent calls to `QThread::currentThread()` during logging affect the performance significantly?

Tags: c++, qt, logging, concurrency, qthread

In my multi-threaded application, with every log I intend to print the thread information. For that, I have to invoke `QThread::currentThread()->objectName()` every time.

Here is its [source code](https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qthread.cpp.html):

`QThread* QThread::currentThread() { return QThreadData::current()->thread.loadAcquire(); }`

Was wondering if it will affect the overall performance **significantly** when the logging increases. I don't have a deterministic way to quantify this information myself.

Comment: If you are unable to measure any performance decrease, then it's fair to say that there is no significant performance decrease.

Comment: Logging will almost always impact performance and IMO should be kept to a minimum.  I've found (decades of experience) that if you have sufficient unit tests you know your code works and there is almost no need for logging (other than what your customers want to have logged).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In latest Qt, it is implemented with `std::memory_order_acquire`. According to [the document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Release-Acquire_ordering), "No additional CPU instructions are issued for this synchronization mode" in x86.

Assume you are using this on intel machines, this would be good.